# Visual Studio Code: Text and cursor position are not correct

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I'm experiencing a strange behavior from the integrated visual studio code console. The text is not well-formatted and the cursor is not well-positioned:

[image]

Software versions:

- Windows 10 Pro;
- Visual studio Code 1.55.2;

I already tried:

- Close the visual studio code and open again;
- closing all instances of integrated terminals and opened them again;
- Use cmd instead of powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I finally found out the *PowerShell* was selected as the *default terminal profile*. After changing it to *Command Prompt*, the feel and look were back to normal.

Follow the steps to change the *default terminal profile*:

1. Open the select box on the top corner of the terminal;
   [image]
2. Choose the options "Select Default Profile";
   [image]
3. Then select Command Prompt.
   [image]